# 0% battery level of touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen

My Ubuntu is reporting at Settings->Power a device "CUST0000:00 04F3:2751" as 0% battery.

I just discovered that this device is my laptop touchscreen.

Sometimes I receive a message saying that this device has not enough power and will stop working.

Then my touchscreen stops working.

I don't think that could be a separate battery to supply the touchscreen and this happens even with the notebook plugged in external power.

Is there anyway to disable this power management of my touchscreen? I think this battery is mistaken and this device should even have a separate battery level.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10. My notebook is a Dell Inspiron 5491 2n1.